# Limpiar salida de diccionario python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, tuplas

Con la siguiente query de mysql en python en una de las tablas de mi base de datos:

```
query = "select custom_id from tgrupo"
cursor.execute(query)
data3 = cursor.fetchall()
```

me da la siguiente salida :
[('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('3',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('1',), ('2',)]

como podría limpiar esto para quitarle la coma y las comillas simples?, necesito comparar unos valores simples, ejm: 1,2,3 etc.. con lo que esta dentro de este diccionario pero con esas comillas y coma no puedo hacerlo

Comment: Lo que muestras no es un diccionario sino una lista en la que cada uno de sus elementos es una tupla (por eso los paréntesis y la coma). Cada tupla tiene un solo elemento que es una cadena (por eso las comillas). No necesitas "limpiar" nada, sino procesar la lista de tuplas como sea preciso. ¿Qué necesitas exactamente? ¿A qué te refieres con "comparar unos valores simples"? ¿Ver por ejemplo si en la lista retornada aparece el número 3?

Answer (score 0):

No se si entiendo bien la pregunta dado que esa salida no es un diccionario pero si lo que quieres es tener una lista del estilo [1, 2, 3], es decir, que tenga solo valores numéricos yo partiría por modificar la consulta a la base de datos para que te traiga los valores distintos de `''`.

Con eso y si no quieres transformar el tipo de los outputs desde la consulta haría lo siguiente para transforma los datos:

```
data3 = [int(v[0]) for v in data3 if v[0].isnumeric()]
```

Talvez no sea necesario hacer el filtro previo de datos pero al no conocer la naturaleza ni extensión de la tabla ni del campo prefiero realizar ese trabajo previo desde la base de datos